# What is causing my images to corrupt during FTP transfer to Go Daddy server?

Tags: drupal-7, data-migration

I'm having a host of problems with migrating my site to my Go Daddy shared hosting server.

The issue I have is that none of my images show up. They do not show up as broken links but there is no image displayed. I am outputting the images as links, and the link area is appropriate to the image, but again no image is displayed. I've moved the codebase to two different development machines (win and linux) and I have no issues in setting them up. I believe that this is an ftp issue. As this is a shared hosting account I don't have access to anything besides ftp (no sftp).

I can confirm that I have all appropriate permissions and so on. I am following normal migration protocol, namely: 1) set up blank site, 2) install my dbase, 3) copy sites folder to server, 4) change settings.php.

I have even tried to ftp using binary explicitly, but again no luck. It is also corrupting my fonts as well, but the images are more imperative.

Any ideas? I don't want to manually upload all my images.

For reference, they are in a 744 folder, and the images have 644 permissions.

UPDATE:
So, I uploaded one of the images manually into my content through the drupal interface. It was placed in the same folder as the other images with 664 permissions. I tested changing the other images' permissions, with no luck. Which seems point back to an image corruption issue, which I assume has to happen in transit for lack of a better explanation.

UPDATE 2:
I tried to run a database update, and there the Drupal Drop logo is a broken link. This suggests that the files are getting corrupted on the server. This however, is a file that should have just come with the drupal install, so now I am at a total loss.

Comment: check permissions on the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, ftp does in fact corrupt image files sometimes, especially when you're transferring large numbers of files. The easiest way to work around this is to archive the files that you want to ftp and transfer the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your code vs. the image files names and extensions, hosting in probably unix/linux and the file system is case sensitive; if this does not work try to look into file paths backslashes vs. forward slashes. 
If Go Daddy has a file manager (I'm sure it does), access your images from the file manager and check: they have right case sensitive names and paths and tagged accordingly as images.
hope it helps

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Comment: I've moved the site between a windows box and a ubuntu test server, no issues there. It does like a few of the images files are getting converted to text encoding, but they preserve their correct extensions, and so forth...really, really, frustrating.

Comment: The file names, seem right, but with some the encoding is text vs image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an ftp issue. To make sure, check whether all the images files have been uploaded to the server. Afterwards, check the file permissions for the image folder/s. Set it to 775 or 777.
If this doesn't solve the issue. just upload a sample image to separate folder and try check it's links (forward and back slashes, case etc) till you can get that image shown properly. Afterwards, apply it to the other folder/s.

Comment: the folder is 744 and the images themselves as 644. As, above, I manually uploaded one image. It was placed in the folder with my images (where it should be) but with 664 permissions. Tried that change on my other images, no luck.